# Type checking "now" abstraction with mypy

Tags: python, python-datetime, mypy, python-typing

Trying to decouple an application from passing time I'm using a simple TimeProvider abstraction:

```py
# foo.py
import datetime as dt
from typing import Protocol

class TimeProvider(Protocol):
    def now(self) -> dt.datetime: ...

def myfunc(timeprovider: TimeProvider = dt.datetime):
    # do stuff dependent on time
    pass


class FakeTimeProvider:
    def __init__(self, time: dt.datetime):
        self.time = time

    def now(self) -> dt.datetime:
        return self.time

myfunc(dt.datetime)
myfunc(FakeTimeProvider(dt.datetime(2021, 12, 2)))
```

Running `mypy foo.py` gives the following errors:

```
➜ mypy foo.py
foo.py:7: error: Incompatible default for argument "timeprovider" (default has type "Type[datetime]", argument has type "TimeProvider")
foo.py:19: error: Argument 1 to "myfunc" has incompatible type "Type[datetime]"; expected "TimeProvider"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Any ideas of what is going on? Is there something wrong with the TimeProvider definition? I don't understand the error as `dt.datetime` has a [`now` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now)

Comment: `dt.datetime` is presumably a class (a `Type[TimeProvider]`). Your type hint `timeprovider: TimeProvider` suggests you want an instance (a `TimeProvider`)

Comment: As I understand Protocol is for static duck typing, so anything that has a method `now` should pass the type check

Comment: yes, but the class itself doesn't have a method `now`. Only instances do. You're passing the class, not an instance

Comment: you know, i think i'm wrong saying the class doesn't have a method `now`. `now` is a `classmethod`

Answer (score 0):

When you write: `def myfunc(timeprovider: TimeProvider = dt.datetime)` you are asking for an `instance` of `TimeProvider`, but `dt.datetime` is a type non an instance. So you could do: `def myfunc(timeprovider: TimeProvider = dt.datetime(1,2,3))` and this is ok for mypy. If you want to pass a class not an instance, you must do: `def myfunc(timeprovider: TimeProvider = Type[dt.datetime])`, like in this code:

```
import datetime as dt
from typing import Protocol, Type


class TimeProvider(Protocol):

    def now(self) -> dt.datetime: ...


def myfunc(timeprovider: Type[TimeProvider]=dt.datetime):
    # do stuff dependent on time
    pass


class FakeTimeProvider:

    def __init__(self, time: dt.datetime):
        self.time = time

    def now(self) -> dt.datetime:
        return self.time


myfunc(dt.datetime)
myfunc(FakeTimeProvider)
```